# ClickOnce: Publish a child project together with main project

Tags: c#, deployment, clickonce

I have a VS Project containing 2 projects. One is the main Project called "main" which is an executable. The second project called "main-ext" is also an executable, but it is an extension to the first one. It has "main" as a reference because it uses some of main's types.

I'd now like to make a ClickOnce publish of "main" that also includes "main-ext". I have already successfully set up ClickOnce for "main". But I cannot include the output generated from "main-ext" in that publish.

I then found out that you somehow need to include the files from "main-ext" into the project of "main" in order for ClickOnce to deploy them.

Now, with that in mind I have tried the following:

1. Add "main-ext" as reference to "main". This obviously does not work because of circular references.
2. Add the output EXE of "main-ext" manually as "Content" with "Copy Always" to the project "main". While this does work, it has a huge problem. If I should ever delete the output files (or run Build > Clean), I can't get the solution to build anymore. Because "main-ext" needs "main" to build, and "main" needs the output of "main-ext" to build. Same circular references, just a little different.

Any ideas?

The next step I'd try would be to refactor "main" and move all the common types and things, that "main" and "main-ext" share, into a dedicated third project, a class library. But because the project is rather large and complicated, I'd like to leave that as an option of last resort.

Thanks.

Comment: Refactoring sounds like a best option

Answer (score 0):

Look into modifying the ClickOnce's manifest. The idea is:

- Main doesn't reference the ext
- build ClickOnce for main
- publish ClickOnce
- open .application in [ManifestManagerUtility](https://compositewpf.codeplex.com/releases/view/14771) (alternatively you can do that using ClickOnce API, I think)
- add reference to your main-ext
- re-sign the manifest.

Then you can allow your users to download a new version. Both files should be installed on client's machines.

Have a look at [this chapter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg405497(v=pandp.40).aspx#sec5) in Prism documentation, it contains a step by step description of a very similar scenario.